Single Machine Job Scheduling With Release Dates and No Idling Constraint
I'm trying to model a linear job scheduling optimisation problem. There is a single machine and N jobs $J_1, J_2, ..., J_N$. Each job consists of one step with processing time $p_1, p_2, ..., p_N$. Each job also has a release date $r_1, ..., r_N$. I want to minimise the average completion time (defined as $startTime_i + p_i - r_i$). I have the normal constraints, such as $startTime_i > 0$, ordering constraints ($x_{ij} + x_{ji} = 1$ where $x_{ij}$ means task order), and I have $S_j >= S_i + p_i - M (1 - x_{ij})$ for the starting times. However, I want to add a constraint so that the machine cannot be idle. If a job finishes and there is one job, I want the machine to pick that job even if it would be shorter to wait until a short job arrives. How could I add that constraint?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4910176/single-machine-job-scheduling-with-release-dates-and-no-idling-constraint

Introduce binary decision variables $y_{ij}$ to indicate that job $i$ immediately precedes job $j$, and impose indicator constraints
$$y_{ij} = 1 \implies S_j = S_i + p_i,$$
which you can alternatively linearize via big-M constraints
$$-M(1-y_{ij}) \le S_j - (S_i + p_i) \le M(1-y_{ij}).$$
To avoid the solver returning $y \equiv 0$, introduce a dummy ending job $N+1$, and impose
$$\sum_{j=1}^{N+1} y_{ij} = 1$$
for $i<N+1$ (that is, for all $i$ except the dummy).  You don't need variables $y_{N+1,j}$ because no job follows the dummy.

Thanks! How can I activate those binary variables?

For your edit, what happens to the last job? $$\sum_j y_{ij} = 1$$ means that all jobs must have a preceding job.

No, that constraint forces each job $i$ (except the dummy) to have exactly one successor job $j$.  The last real job gets the dummy as its successor.

I see. But if I have a finite list of jobs, not all jobs will have one successor. There will be one job that is the last job of the sequence. Also, not sure I understand what you mean by each job $i$ except the dummy.

By successor, I mean immediate successor.  Think of the dummy job as $N+1$, and   $\sum_{j=1}^{N+1} y_{ij}=1$ is imposed for $i\in{1,\dots,N}$.

Oh, I thinks I understand now! I need to create a dummy job (any particular way?). Let's say a job with a very long processing time and immediate release date. That way it forces it. Thank you very much!

Yes, immediate release date for the dummy.  A processing time of $0$ would be more natural for the dummy, but $p_{N+1}$ will not be used in any constraints.

I added your constraint to the problem and it works well at not accepting idling time. However, now instead of starting at $startTime = 0$ it starts later. Is it possible to force start time to be 0?

To force starting the project at $0$, you can introduce a dummy start job $0$, with release date $0$ and processing time $0$, and fix $S_0=0$.  That way, whichever job $j$ is the immediate successor of $0$ will have $S_j=S_0+p_0=0+0$.

I tried that, but for some reason I get overlapping jobs. I added the 2 dummies and now have $\sum_{j = 1}^{N+2} y_{ij} = 1$ and forced $S_0 = 0$

I suspect that you omitted some of the indicator constraints, which should be imposed even if $i$ is the dummy start job or $j$ is the dummy end job.

@RalphMelish, would you please, elaborate more on I want the machine to pick that job even if it would be shorter to wait until a short job arrives.? This phrase somewhat contradicts the release date. Also, if you have a release date, it should be normal to have the idle times in an optimal solution. In your case, an active schedule. Also, why not try to use $C_{max}$ function as the objective? It is naturally designed to force the schedule to be non-delay.

Dear @RobPratt, suppose there exist two tasks that should be scheduled on one resource. The processing times as well as release dates are ${ (5,0), (3,6) }$ respectively. In the optimal solution, it obviously executes $task_1$ first and $task_2$ in consequence. It yields an optimal (active, but not necessarily non-delay) schedule with a total compilation time equal to $9$. I think what the questioner mentioned as $x_{i,j}$ works to ensure task $i$ is immediately being processed before task $j$. Now, I am unsure understanding your idea to define dummy tasks and the new constraint.

Thank you, @RobPratt! It was missing one constraint, tasks can only succeed other tasks one time, $\sum_{i = 1}^{N+2} y_{ij} = 1$, for all $j$ minus the dummies where $i != j$. That fixed it.

@A.Omidi The OP enforces only $S_j\ge$ rather than $S_j=$, and the $x_{ij}$ variable indicates whether job $i$ is processed some time (not necessarily immediately) before job $j$.

Dear @RobPratt, I think defining the model only based on assigning variables like $z_{j,m}$ and sequencing variables like $x_{i,j}$ can solve the problem with an active schedule as an optimal solution. Although, I am unsure how the questioner defined the rest of the problem.

@A.Omidi, what I meant by the sentence you highlighted is that I want the machine to never be idle. If only a very long job is available, I want the machine to pick that job even if a really short job is arriving in 1 unit of time. I hope this helps clarify

@RalphMelish, If in your problem you do not define any kinds of weights on the tasks or there is no preemption you allowed in the schedule, what you mentioned should be done by default. (One task is being assigned to a machine and executed until its processing time is finished). In my tiny example in the comment, while there exists one unit of idle time, this is the best/optimal schedule to minimize idle time. Unless the planner wants to enforce whose own schedule that may cause the sub-optimal solution.

Hi, @RobPratt. Thank you, the model now works well. I was wondering how would you change the constraint for when no jobs are possible continuously? Meaning, idleness is forced because the next job hasn't arrived yet.

If it is not possible to achieve zero idle time, you could instead minimize idle time (equivalently, minimize the makespan) as a primary objective and then minimize average completion time as a secondary objective.

@RobPratt, ok, that makes sense. I would need to rewrite the model then. The main objective would be to minimise the sum of starting times? How could I define idle time?

To minimize the makespan, you can just minimize the start time of the dummy ending job.

Thanks! The model takes a very long time to compute. Are there any optimal scheduling policies? Like Shortest Processting Time first? Or without preemptiveness and without idleness (unless forced) there is no optimal algorithm?

I'm not aware of a specialized algorithm for this, but implementing a heuristic and using the resulting schedule as a starting solution could speed up the MILP solver.

@RobPratt, thank you! And if I add a deadline to the problem, are there any algorithms?
